# How to send multiple values in a single alert notification email in Grafana?

Tags: grafana, grafana-alerts

I am using InfluxDb. I create a table called weather with few columns like temp, humidity, city, state, country, zip.

I set an alert notification for temperature. When value of temp column of any city touch 40.0, Grafana sends email notification to recipients.

Now, I want to show other information like city, state, zip along with temp value in Email. Is it possible? If yes could you guide me how to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The only variables you can use in the notification part are labels. if the information you want to send is a label you can use the general syntax ${label} to reference it

Comment: Could you share any link about implementation of ${label}?

Comment: https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/alerting/add-notification-template/